Summary in master document does not show subdocument's title
I'm creating an master document and already have an subdocument ready. Added it ok, and everything allright until I created an summary.
The summary was ok, except for one detail: the subdocument title was not added as root of the summary for that chapter/subdocument.
How I could do that?
Notes:

the subdocument title already have the document title style.
LibreOffice Writer: 7.1.8.1 on Windows 10 x64

